# when I use composer update or update new extensions, get error says verify that they are enabled in your .ini files

Tags: php, laravel

The error message is like this:

> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini
>   files: -- -     -/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini
>      - /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
>      - /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/xdebug.ini

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLEOA.png)

I don't know how to enable this file. But when I go into that path, it exists. Can everyone help me solve that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you are using apache run `sudo service apache2 restart` or if you are using php-fpm run `sudo service php-fpm restart`

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried but still doesn't work. Looks like miss something or need to setup something to enable that files

Comment: @TianyiJiang Can you please share completer error stack

Comment: @Sehdev I add the whole error to the description. Could you please help me have a look? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `imagick` to resolve this issue:

As per the `Laravel Medialibrary` requirements

> The Medialibrary package requires PHP 5.5.9+ and Laravel 5.1.0+. To
>   create derived images GD needs to be installed on your server. If you
>   want to create PDF thumbnails Imagick is also required.

`GD` and `Imagick` can be installed using apt-get on `Ubuntu and Debian`:

```
$ apt-get install php-gd imagemagick php-imagick
```

Or with `yum on CentOS`:

```
$ yum install php70u-gd ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel
```

**Note:** Root access to your server is probably required.

**OR**

To resolve this add below lines in your `composer.json:`

```
{
    "require": {
       "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^7.0.0" // add this line
    },
   "provide": { // add this
       "ext-imagick": "*" //add this
   },  // add this
    "require-dev": {

    }
}
```

and run your command again

References:

https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v3/requirements/#

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/issues/1480

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/issues/1553